# Classification of Proper Maps between domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces

Suppose $f:D_1\to D_2$ is a continuous map between domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $f$ is proper iff for every sequence  $(x_n)$ in $D_1$ which accumulates only on $\partial D_1\cup\{\infty\}$, we have that $(f(x_n))$ accumulates only on  $\partial D_2\cup\{\infty\}$. [$\partial D$ denotes boundary of $D$.]

> **Definition**: A map $f:X \to Y$ is called **proper** if $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact for every set $K$ compact in $Y$.

Can someone please give some hints/ideas. Is this problem a consequence of some famous theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "domain" we mean an open, connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Note, in particular, that if $D$ is a domain and $K\subseteq D$, then $K\cap \partial D=\varnothing$. Let's solve this using the contrapositives.

First suppose that $f$ is not proper. Then there exists a compact set $K\subseteq D_2$ such that $f^{-1}(K)$ is not compact. But since $f$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}(K)$ is already closed, so it must be unbounded. Then there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $f^{-1}(K)$ such that $\Vert x_n\Vert\to\infty$, (so $(x_n)$ only accumulates at $\left\{\infty\right\}$). On the other hand, $(f(x_n))\subseteq K$, so $(f(x_n))$ accumulates at some point of $K$, which does not belong to $\partial D_2\cup\left\{\infty\right\}$.

Conversely, suppose that there exists some sequence $(x_n)$ in $D_1$ which accumulates only at $\partial D_1\cup\left\{\infty\right\}$, but $(f(x_n))$ accumulates at some point not in $\partial D_2\cup\left\{\infty\right\}$, i.e., at some point of $D_2$. Considering a subsequence if necessary, assume that $f(x_n)$ converges to a point $y\in D_2$. The set $K=\left\{f(x_n):n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}\cup\left\{y\right\}$ is compact in $D_2$. Let's show that $f^{-1}(K)$ is not compact. If $\left\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ is unbounded, then $f^{-1}(K)$, which contains this set, is unbounded as well, so we are done. If not, then $\left\{x_n\right\}$ accumulates at some point $z$ of $\partial D_1$. Since $D_1$ is open, $D_1$ is disjoint with $\partial D_1$, so $z\not\in D_1$ and in particular $z\not\in f^{-1}(K)$. This shows that $f^{-1}(K)$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and thus it cannot be compact in $D_1$ (recall that compactness is independent of the ambient space).

Comment: +1,Nice and easy solution.can you please tell me the motivation for converse part?

Comment: @ArpitKansal Well, someitmes (for this kind of exercise), it is easier to construct things from others than proving something holds for every object of some king. In other words, we want to prove implications of the form "$\exists$ an object with certain property$\Rightarrow$\exists another object with some other property". That's why I considered the contrapositives to begin with.

Comment: @ArpitKansal For the converse, I began with a sequence (by hypothesis) and had to, somehow, construct a compact set. The construction I made is pretty standard: take a bounded set (in this case the image of the sequence), and close it (the argument with taking a subsequence is actually just to simplify the argument). Since I'm simply "following the breadcrumbs", this compact set, which encodes our initial sequence, should have the property we want in the end. The argument "a set either is unbounded or accumulates at some point of $\mathbb{R}^n$" is also pretty standard. I hope this helped.

Comment: Dear @Luiz, Ahh Beautiful.Thank You!Regards,