# Non-existence of conformal mappings between open subsets

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck with an exercise which is concerned with a proof that various open subsets of the complex plane are not conformally equivalent.

> Show that no two of the following open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ are conformally equivalent.
>
> $U_1=\mathbb{C}, \ U_2=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \  |z|<1 \} ,U_3=U_2 \setminus \{0\}, \
> U_4=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \ | 1 < |z| <2 \}$
>
> (Hint: In the case of $U_3,U_4$ you may want to consider what kind of singularities a holomorphic mapp on $U_3$ can have at $z_0=0$.)

This is what I have so far:

I know that any conformal mapping will also be biholomorphic and vice versa.

Suppose that there is a map $f: U_3 \to U_4$. Because $f$ is bounded on a punctured neighborhood of $0$ it follows that $0$ is a removable singularity. So there is a holomorphic map

$$\bar{f}: U_2 \to \mathbb{C}, \ \bar{f}=
\begin{cases} 
f(z), & z \ \neq 0 \\
w_0,  &  \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Case 1: $w_0 \in U_4$

Because f is bijective there is $z_1$ such that $\bar{f}(z_1)=\bar{f}(0)=w_0$. So there are neighborhoods $A_0, A_1$ such that $A_0 \cap A_1=\varnothing$. Let $g$ be the inverse of $f$. Then $\bar{f}(A_0)=g^{-1}(A_0)$ and since $g$ is holomorphic and therefore continous it follows that $\bar{f}(A_0)$ is a neighborhood of $w_0$. If I can show that $\bar{f}(A_1)$ is also a neighborhood of $w_0$ then $\bar{f}(A_0) \cap \bar{f}(A_1)$ is also a nonempty neighborhood of $w_0$. Then there is $w' \in \bar{f}(A_0) \cap \bar{f}(A_1)$ and $z \in A_0,z' \in A_1$ such that $f(z)=w=f(z')$ which contradicts the injectivity of $f$.

Case 2: $w_0 \notin U_4$

Because $\bar{f}$ is holomorphic and nonconstant and $U_2$ is a domain (connected and open set) it follows from the open mapping theorem that $\bar{f}(U_2)=U_4 \cup \{f(w_0)\}$ is also a domain  which is a contradiction since the set is not connected.

In the case of $U_3, U_2$ I can use the same argument as above.

In the case of $U_1,U_i  \ i \in \{2,3,4\}$ I can use Liouville's theorem.

Consider $U_2, U_4$. Suppose there is a conformal map $f: U_2 \to U_4 $.

I know that $U_2$ is contained in the inner ring of $U_4$.

I have two problems.

1) In the case of $U_3,U_4$ I do not see how to show that $\bar{f}(A_1)$ is a neighborhood of $w_0$.

2) I do not see how to proceed in the case of $U_2, U_4$. I think it is possible to conclude that $f$ is not injective. But I fail to see how this follows.

\Edit: I am not allowed to use arguments involving homeomorphisms or the fundamental group.

Comment: $U_3-U_2$ and $U_4-U_2$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Very true. But unfortunately I am not allowed to use homeomorphisms or the fundamental group.

Comment: $U_4-U_3$ has already an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304924/non-existence-of-a-proper-holomorphic-map-from-the-punctured-unit-disc-to-an-ann?rq=1)